# WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW - Where are my new lines?

Tags: c++, windows, console

I'm trying to learn how to use a screen buffer, and I made a mistake that I do not understand. These are the settings for my screen buffer:

```
wchar_t* screen = new wchar_t[nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight];
for (int i = 0; i < nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight; i++) {
    screen[i] = L' ';
}

HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;

WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW(hConsole, screen, (nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight), { 0,0 }, &dwBytesWritten);
```

I manage to print to it my 2D array but it is weird that it's lying flat in my terminal window (see link to print screen).

[Small print screen of my failed 2D array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1QQ3.png)

It's as if all the new lines have been removed. This is my loop that prints my 2D array to "screen".

```
int g = 0;

while (g < 100) {
    WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW(hConsole, screen, (nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight), { 0,0 }, &dwBytesWritten);

    for (int i = 0; i < field.difficulty; i++) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));

    }

    for (int y = 0; y < field.nFieldHeight; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < field.nFieldWidth; x++) {

            screen[(y + 2) * field.nFieldWidth + (x + 2)] = field.matrix[x][y];
        }

    }
}
```

Is it possible that I need to write to a coordinate in the screen buffer every time I print a character?

Answer (score 0):

By default the console window is re-sizable and the this causes the output to wrap. You can prevent this by using the following:

```
// Get console window
HWND hwndWindow = GetConsoleWindow();

// Prevent resize & maximize
LONG lFlags = GetWindowLong(hwndWindow , GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX & ~WS_SIZEBOX & ~WS_HSCROLL;
SetWindowLong(hwndWindow , GWL_STYLE, lFlags);

// Get console handle
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

// Set window and buffer size
_SMALL_RECT consoleRect = { 0, 0, SCREEN_W - 1, SCREEN_H - 1 };
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hConsole, { SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H });
SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, TRUE, &consoleRect);
```